# How can I show this 2 div side by side?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Into a page I have the following

```
<div id="submitEventButtonDiv">
    <div id="wwctrl_backButton" align="right">
        <input id="backButton" type="submit" onclick="return clickSubmitButton();" value="Back">
    </div>

    <div id="wwctrl_submitEventButton" align="right">
        <input id="submitEventButton" type="submit" onclick="return clickSubmitButton();" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is an external div having **id="submitEventButtonDiv"** that contains 2 divs containing in turn 2 input fields.

Obviously when the 2 input field are displayed appear one below the other (because they are contained into a div that is block element).

How can I display one beside the other? (I can't delete the div that contains each input field because it is automatically rendered by a tag library that I am using, this that I have post is the rendered HTML obtained from a page that us Struts 2 tag library that wrap HTML following its logic, so in this case I can only work on CSS to do it)

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just display the child elements inline.

```
#submitEventButtonDiv > div {
display:inline;
}
```

codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEmaed

Comment: ok, solved by myself just floating the main #submitEventButtonDiv div on right :-)

Comment: add      [type=submit] {
               float:right;
             }

Comment: What exactly is the difference to float:right the #submitEventButtonDiv container or to float right one of the 2 buttons?

Comment: Floating the whole container will make it inline, floating the buttons will just make the buttons inline.  It can sometimes cause inheritance issues.  But in your case I don't think it will be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your cross browser needs, use flexbox:

```
#submitEventButtonDiv {
    display: flex;
}
```

Will make all of the children flex items, which by default, stack horizontally, like you want.

Comment: only a viable solution if the end user uses >= IE10: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Akshay Thanks! Feel free to edit that in, I'll accept it. (Although, why the `float: right`)?

Comment: @SecondRikudo just that if you remove `display:flex` you can see that it is aligned to the right  because of this ` <div id="wwctrl_backButton" align="right">` so i gave a `float:right`

Answer (score 0):

If you float them both they'll be positioned next to each other. Adding

```
#submitEventButtonDiv > div {
    float:left;  
    display:inline;  
}
```

To your css should position them both to the left of the page next to eachother.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner div IDs are always same, then you can add the following styles in your css:

```
div#wwctrl_backButton {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
}
div#wwctrl_submitEventButton{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This generates the desired effect.

```
#submitEventButtonDiv > div {
display:inline;
float:right;
}
```